# Using HTML Script with Blob

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I've seen Wix use `<script src="blob:">` on their site.

We are familiar with using this technique for videos from Youtube and image files on some sites. But using it in a script was very interesting and interesting.

> I've done some research on the subject but haven't found much.

What do you think are the pros and cons of this technique and should it be used?

Does it also guarantee the privacy of the scripts?

Comment: 1_ Can't really see the benefit of this approach and I guess it wan't be good for your SEO
2_ Does it guarantee the privacy of the scripts ? ... If the browser can process it, then any one can see it, just like Youtube videos with the right manipulation you can always download them.

Comment: Youtube uses blob:// URIs with MediaSource objects, not with Blobs, completely unrelated.